# Wifi power management turns back on when connecting

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04, power-management

I've been having wifi connectivity issues, and I've narrowed the problem down.  Wifi power management seems to mess with my connectivity.  I can turn it off with:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

But every time I connect to a network, power management turns back on.  I've searched for solutions, but I've only found ways to make sure power management stays off when you login, reboot, etc.  I think I might be able to sort this out with systemd hooks, but I don't know how that all works.

Here's what I've got:

- Ubuntu 15.04
- Lenovo thinkpad yoga
- Intel Wireless 7260
- driver: `iwlwifi`
- kernel version `3.19.0-22-generic`

Any ideas?

This is not a duplicate of [Why doesn't Ubuntu automatically disable wireless networking when a wired connection is active?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266662/why-doesnt-ubuntu-automatically-disable-wireless-networking-when-a-wired-connec) , but information from that post was relevant to this.

Comment: I just posted an answer to a different question that I think applies to your question, too:  http://askubuntu.com/a/649707/25618

Comment: I think I figured it out from your post!  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Ubuntu automatically disable wireless networking when a wired connection is active?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/266662/why-doesnt-ubuntu-automatically-disable-wireless-networking-when-a-wired-connec)

Comment: Aha thanks! I read various things about power management causing issues but didn't know how to turn it off. Check out [the difference it makes](http://hastebin.com/ebeyexohes.vhdl).

Answer (score 1):

From [the comment by @waltinator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649706/wifi-power-management-turns-back-on-when-connecting#comment932746_649706) here's what I did.  As of right now, it looks like this has fixed things.

Make a file in `/etc/network/if-up.d` called `wifipower` (the name doesn't matter):

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/network/if-up.d/wifipower
```

And write in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Save and make it executable with

```
sudo chmod a+x wifipower
```

Basically, every time a connection is established the script wifipower will be executed and turn power management off.